# How can I make my main form wait for a result from a custom dialog that I have created?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to make a search feature that has a couple more open ended options, and before I implement it for both options, I want to get it working for one, understandably.

What I decided to do was make a custom dialog and use it to display the list that will result from the inputted search criteria.

Here is the code that calls the dialog:

```
Sub search(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim temp As String
    Dim tempSplit As String()
    Dim check As Boolean = False
    'instance creation of dialog box
    Dim extendSearch As New TypeClassSearch()
    Select Case cmbSearch.Text
        Case "Name"
            'working and appropiate code
            Exit Select

        Case "Number"
            'working and appropriate code
            Exit Select

        Case "Type"
            check = True
            'shows dialog
            extendSearch.Show()
            'doesn't wait for input from the dialog and just goes through the code before user can interact
            If extendSearch.DialogResult() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To pokemonList.Length - 1
                    If extendSearch.selection = pokemonList(i) Then
                        temp = weaknesses(i)
                        tempSplit = temp.Split(CChar("\"))
                        weaknesses(i) = ""
                        For k As Integer = 0 To tempSplit.Length - 1
                            If k <> tempSplit.Length - 1 Then
                                weaknesses(i) += tempSplit(k) + ", "
                            Else
                                weaknesses(i) += tempSplit(k)
                            End If
                        Next
                        temp = resist(i)
                        tempSplit = temp.Split(CChar("\"))
                        resist(i) = ""
                        For k As Integer = 0 To tempSplit.Length - 1
                            If k <> tempSplit.Length - 1 Then
                                resist(i) += tempSplit(k) + ", "
                            Else
                                resist(i) += tempSplit(k)
                            End If
                        Next
                        lblNum.Text = pokedexNum(i)
                        lblPkmn.Text = pokemonList(i)
                        lblType.Text = typings(i)
                        lblClass.Text = classifications(i)
                        lblWeak.Text = weaknesses(i)
                        lblResist.Text = resist(i)
                        lblPkdxX.Text = pokedexX(i)
                        lblPkdxY.Text = pokedexY(i)
                    End If
                Next
            End If

                Exit Select
        Case "Class"
                'hold code, next extended criteria
                Exit Select
    End Select

    If check = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Pokemon Not Found. Please check your spelling or try again.")
    End If
End Sub
```

My dialog box is a simple bit of code:

```
Private Sub OK_Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK_Button.Click
        Me.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
        selection = CStr(chkSearch.SelectedItem)
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change, `extendSearch.Show()` to `extendSearch.ShowDialog()`

Comment: Wow that was an easy fix... Thanks, though! I'll accept your answer when it lets me.